# Avoid violation of DRY with ternary?

Tags: java, dry, ternary-operator

Here's what I have.

```
Map data = new HashMap<>(); // assume this has been populated

public int getLastestVersion() {
    // data.get("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT") would be an integer
    return data.get("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT") == null ? 0 : (int)data.get("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT");
}
```

I'm trying to avoid violating DRY, but I want to be able to keep the simplicity of the ternary. Is there something I can do?

Comment: If you're trying to avoid repeating yourself, you ought to start by using generics; that's what they're there for.

Comment: @chrylis: That isn't his problem.

Comment: Using something like Groovy that has the Elvis operator makes this very easy.

Comment: @SLaks That's *one* of his problems, in addition to the duplicate `get` call.

Comment: `elvis( data.get("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT"), v->v, 0 )`

Comment: @bayou.io I'm not using Groovy, but thanks.

Comment: no, it's a static helper method you can define in java :) no groovy required.

Comment: @bayou.io Compiler is giving it an error

Comment: elvis is not in the house.

Comment: @bayou.io Right. He's buried behind the [house](http://www.graceland.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java8, you can use [`getOrDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method:

```
return data.getOrDefault("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT", 0);
```

Comment: which could result in `null` :D

Comment: @bayou.io Yes, you are right, if the map contains a key of which the value is `null`.

Comment: yeah, but probably not a problem in OP's app.

Comment: @bayou.io right on that one. In my case, it's impossible for null to be assigned to the value, so this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could assign the result to a `final` local variable. That way the compiler is free to inline it, and you don't have to repeat the calls to get in your `Map<String, Integer> data`. In Java 8+, something like

```
final Integer v = data.get("PATH_TO_DESIRED_POINT");
return v != null ? v : 0;
```

Comment: You may not need the intValue() bit because autoboxing.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I assume you mean [autounboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#d5e17099). And I checked, in Java 8 you're right. That's legal.

Comment: I like the temporary variable also because it ensures that it would even work when the map changes and it allows to name the variable descriptive (`pathNum` or something. BTW: the final is a good pratice but hotspot does optimize it anyway.